# Finding performance bottlenecks using profiling feature of firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug, profile

Finally having completed an application, I am about to profile time taken to run javascript functions and optimize them but just that i don't know where to start.

- Do i click the profile button after page loads or after i hit the enter in addressbar?
- How do i find which is taking more time, instead of dwelling too much into unnecessary function codes.
- Maybe some handy set of tips also will help me thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you click the profile button, it starts recording.  And once you click it again, it will stop recording and show you the results of your actions.

So it wouldn't make sense to load the page then hit profile, you would want to hit profile before you load the page so that it records all the js that was executed on load.

A good way to start profiling is to write down several use cases.  Then profile each use case and go from there.

The percent and time columns can help you determine bottlenecks.

Comment: @cOdeNinja by use cases you mean **use case 1 - Dialog rendering time** then i go click Profile button click the button that renders dialog, see what is taking more time? this would mean loads of time to invest ain't it

Comment: Well, if you already know which functions need attention then go directly there.  By use case I meant something like:  use case 1 - Post a comment, use case 2 - Add item to cart....

Comment: Also, by taking a look at the profile snapshot you can quickly spot functions that are taking more time than they should.  You don't necessarily need to dig too deep.

Comment: @cOdeNinja can you explain how to profile in Chrome web inspector

Comment: Very similar... in the Profiles tab, at the very bottom left corner you will see a couple of icons.  The solid circle is your profile start and stop.  Hope this helps!